# Confidence level smaller than 0 with python linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My have the share prices df2[x] below as Y:

```
2018-09-05    6.22
2018-09-06    6.19
2018-09-07    6.22
2018-09-10    6.24
2018-09-11    6.24
```

...

```
2018-12-05    4.65
2018-12-14    0.00
```

short position csvReader5[x] as X:

```
2018-09-06    1.11
2018-09-07    1.04
2018-09-10    1.61
2018-09-11    1.52
2018-09-12    1.61

..
2018-12-05    0.98
2018-12-14    7.00
```

This is my code to calculate confidence level

```
 y = numpy.array(csvReader5[x]).reshape(-1,1)
 X=numpy.array(df2[x]).reshape(-1,1)
 X = preprocessing.scale(X)

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
 clf = LinearRegression()
 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
 confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
Out :-1.08
```

The confidence level I got changes every time I run it and it is always smaller than 1. I thought confidence level is the same as R square hence should always be between (0,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From sklearn documentation:

```
score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

The coefficient `R^2` is defined as `(1 - u/v)`, where u is the residual sum of squares `((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum()` and v is the total sum of squares `((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum()`. The best possible score is 1.0 and **it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse)**.  A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

Comment: What does arbitrarily worse mean? as in the coefficient is negative ?

Comment: @Candice If your y_preds is worse than y_true.mean(), you will have negative score. The more different your y_preds from y_true the smaller the score.